# How to make Outlook actually ring my phone (like a phone call) when I have a meeting coming up?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a problem being late for meetings, even when I'm just sitting at my desk working on something that I could easily set aside while I attend the meeting. The main problem is that I just forget the meeting is coming up.

I'm looking at the Outlook mobile settings (iPhone), Calendar, "Notifications Sound".

The only choices are 8 or 9 very soft, short-duration bleeps of about one second.

Is the any possible way to make Outlook alert me with an actual **long, loud, repetitive sound**, like a phone call until I pick it up and answer it?

Comment: Outlook Calendar reminders both make a sound and Pop Up as well.  That gets my attention.

Comment: I have the same wish and issue. My work around is to set alarms on my phone.

Comment: I found a similar idea in uservoice and voted for it, I suggest you could also vote for it : https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293349-outlook-for-ios/suggestions/33952414-add-longer-sounds-for-notifications